# Добавление текстового префикса

Tags: python

есть строка
х=[1,3,4,5]
и к ней надо добавить префикс Х.
чтобы получилось
х=[Х1,Х3,Х4,Х5]
подскажите лузеру)

Comment: С виду это не строка, а список из целых чисел. Что всё-таки на входе точно?

Comment: конечно не строка а список! Описка)

Comment: Так, хорошо, а на выходе тогда что - список строк или список переменных? )

Comment: Список конешно)

Comment: переменных !!!!

Comment: @CrazyElf ну хотя бы направление, в какую сторону двигаться)

Comment: Смотрите ответ roddar92, там по частям вся инфа есть, просто надо её вместе собрать )

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно создать массив строк:

```
x = [f'X{i}' for i in x]
```

Не забудьте обернуть результат в кавычки :)

Для создания нескольких переменных код будет аналогичным:

```
for i in x:
    globals()[f'x{i}'] = smth
```

Comment: сейчас выяснится, что на выходе должны быть не строки "Х1", "Х2" и т.д., а переменные ``х1``, ``х2`` :D

Comment: ну ошибся немного) конечно не строка, а список)

Answer (score 1):

```
print(list(map("X".__add__, map(str, x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Подобные темы вроде уже много раз были. Ну вот примерно так:

```
x = [1,3,4,5]
X1 = 11
X3 = 33
X4 = 44
X5 = 55

print([eval(f'X{i}') for i in x]) # через eval
print([globals()[f'X{i}'] for i in x]) # через globals()
```

Вывод:

```
[11, 33, 44, 55]
[11, 33, 44, 55]
```

И стандартное напоминание: старайтесь не использовать `eval`, это опасная практика, мало ли что в строке попадётся.

Comment: Я наверно всё таки неправильно объяснил задачу. Мне кажется всё должно быть как-то проще) Просто привык к нодам, в pyton путаюсь ещё) итак:

Comment: @valerius.spb Если вам нужна просто строка с символами, то смотрите ответ roddar92

Comment: Попробую ещё раз, итак: есть список list = [1,2,3,4,5] и к каждому элементу списка нужно добавить префикс, в данном случае, допустим А, чтобы в результате появился список list = [A1,A2,A3,A4,A5]. Нужен именно список...

Comment: @valerius.spb Как вы написали, так всё-равно нельзя. Можно только с кавычками: `['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']`. Если так пойдёт, то ответы вам уже дали.